# Facebook Like + Send (send not showing)

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-social-plugins

So I'm using Facebook Like combined with the send button using the following HTML5 code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="120" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="dark" data-font="arial">
```

The problem is that the "Send" button flickers for a moment and then disappears.  Note, this is only the case with data-layout=button_count.   When data-layout is set to 'standard', it stays, although shows other undesirable text (in our case).

Nowhere in the documentation that I can find does it say that the data-send=true flag does not render the "send" button when data-layout is set to to "button_count".

This is the case even on the facebook example page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

The fact that the send button flickers and then disappears (EVEN ON THE FACEBOOK EXAMPLE PAGE), leads me to believe this as an error.

Can someone in the know shed some light about what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Andrew, what browsers are you receiving this error?  Have you tested in any other browsers?

Comment: I'm getting the similar issues.  That particular documentation page seems to have some serious problems.

Comment: It seems as though they fixed it, without any code change on my end, the send button is showing up again next to the like for the "button_count" layout. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the Send Button is having some issues currently as you can see by searching in the [bug reports system](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs?search_view=search&search_ids%5B0%5D=119344624828659&&search_statuses%5B0%5D=open).

These two tell me that something is wrong: [Send button opens new tab](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/177102442412197?browse=search_4f99b4d4245973761417571) and [Problem with Like/Send button with data-layout set to 'button_count'](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/299191993489218?browse=search_4f97ebe1524a53b52292044).

I'm not sure that what you're describing is related, but it's not far fetched.

Comment: I marked it as the answer because the bug report you linked to was the exact issue.